# show the MediaController

Tags: android

Is there a way I can have the `MediaController` show always?

```
  videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
  String path = "/sdcard/feiyang/video/sfqx.3GP";
  MediaController m = new MediaController(this);
  videoView.setMediaController(m);
  videoView.setVideoPath(path);
  videoView.start();
```

I'm using `m.show(0);`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

replace the line in your code that creates the MediaController with this:

```
MediaController controller = new MediaController(this){
    @Override
    public void hide() {
        this.show(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void setMediaPlayer(MediaPlayerControl player) {
        super.setMediaPlayer(player);
        this.show();
    }
};
```

then call

```
videoView.setMediaController(controller);
```

in the same way you already are, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

handle Back key event:

```
mController = new MediaController(this) {
    ...

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            ((Activity) mContext).finish();
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```